# The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, apache

I'm running WordPress locally on 127.0.0.1 on Mac OS X Lion. All links work fine. Problem is when I add pages, and set permalinks to the page, and then associate the page with one of my template themes, as shown in this link below:

[image]

I get this:

Not Found
The requested URL /gps-products was not found on this server.

Now I have the same code (including the .htaccess file) and same database on two different Macs running Lion, and it works fine on one but not the other, so I believe the issue is related to the Apache configuration.

Comment: Close-voted as off-top since this deals specifically with server configuration. This might get more attention at Server Fault or Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an Apache and OS X question and not specifically WordPress, but you may need to edit Apache's httpd.conf file to allow .htaccess files to work on the one Mac.

Go to /etc/apache2/ (That's for 10.6; Lion may be different) with the Finder's Go >> Go to Folder... menu item  (or via terminal) and edit httpd.conf and uncomment the instances of `AllowOverride All` in one or more `<Directory ...>` blocks. There may be several. Then restart Apache or reboot the Mac.

See http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/ for the whole process, including editing httpd.conf